# Stable Baselines - model.predict: how to select the GPU

Tags: reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I'm using Stable-Baselines3 and I'd like to test a model I've just trained.

How can I assign a specific GPU to the execution of the `model.predict` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the device to the model when you create it, then `predict` would automatically use the chosen device.

E.g.

```py
model = DQN(..., device='cuda:0', ...)
model.predict(...)    # this would use the cuda:0 device
```

Comment: Thanks Alex.
The full sequence I'll be using is: model creation, model loading, model predict (loading is missing in your example)

Comment: @MarcoM Ah yes, it's missing. As you say looks good. Either you load a pre-trained model, or you create one and train it. Then you use predict (otherwise you'll get a random output from an untrained model).